# Webview image fit on screen

Tags: java, android, image, webview, zooming

This looks like a duplicate, but I got a weird problem.

I use this code:

```
public void showPicture(){
        System.out.println("comicTeller = "+comicTeller);

        WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.removeAllViews();  
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        String base = root.getAbsolutePath().toString();
        String imagePath = "file://"+ base + "/bigflow/dark/"+comicTeller+".jpg";
        String html = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"></body></html>";
        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html","utf-8", "");  

}
```

When I start the app, it works perfect. I also got a "next comic" button, so it goes to the next comic (it is a comic reader). It scales good everytime when I touch the button.  The "next button" calls `showPicture();` and increases the `comicTeller` (comicTeller = comicCounter in english) with 1, so it shows the next picture.

But as soon I zoom in on a comic, and goes to the next comic, it stays zoomed in. I don't know why it does that. I thought my code would reset it again.

So does someone know a solution to "reset" the zoom again. And load the next comic Fit on screen again? I don't really know what is wrong with my code.

If you need more info, please tell me.

Comment: please post zooming code

Comment: @Braj This is the code. WebView has auto zoom function.

`mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);`

Comment: try webView.setInitialScale(0);

Comment: @Braj I think I did something serious wrong. `mWebView.setInitialScale(0);` doesn't change the scale somehow... weird, looking fuurther